# iOS app with cloud based service

Tags: ios, icloud, cloudkit, icloud-drive

I'm trying to create, update, insert records into the iCloud along with my app's ID. I did created my record type in the icloud dashboard and it is working only when the device contains icloud account has been logged in. How to use the icloud service for all the devices which is only using the app ? I saw API access and how to implement the token based access ? Please help me with this problem.

Comment: In order to use CloudKit the user must be logged into iCloud.  I guess you could use the CloudKit Web Services and direct the user to login via a web view, but prompting them to log into iCloud on the device would be easier.

Comment: Thanks and let me try with API access..

Comment: @Paulw11 If permissions are set appropriately, an app can read records from the public database even if the device isn't logged into an iCloud account.

Comment: True. The reference to authentication lead me to assume they are asking about private storage but perhaps the op could confirm.

Comment: @rmaddy It suits my scenario for storing personal data into the icloud after logging in. But, still I just want to see how such permissions are created. Can you please send me any clear link to check that ?

Comment: Read the CloudKit Quick Start in the docs. The permissions are done in the CloudKit dashboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a screenshot of the showing the permissions box.

[image]

You can see from here you can even grant read access to anonymous users if you so wish, although you would be very unwise to do so if your plan was release your app on the apps store for obvious reasons I would hope.